# Probability formula for an event with constant predefined average

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random

There is an oracle in which it generates a random number every one minute. If the random number is smaller than a constant number `target`, it would be called a `hit`.

While the event should be random:

1. How can I create a formula in a way that a `hit` happens on average roughly every **24 hours**?
2. What would be the probability distribution I should use?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: Thanks for the link. Any suggestion on how to improve this question?